# Newsletter Plugin That Allows Multiple Lists?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, newsletter

I have tried a few plugins *(wysija, newsletter, xyz newsletter)*, but no one met my requirements so far.

What I want is each page to have a sign up form and then the person that signs up would be added to a different list depending on the page they signed up from.

I'm looking for premium or free plugins, and want to avoid third party solutions as well.

Comment: Can you please mention the plugins you've already tried?

Comment: wysija, newsletter, xyz newsletter.. I will possibly opt for WordPress Newsletter Plugin by Tribulant..

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can solve this with *any* plugin...

### By Code

Using Wysija [example](http://support.wysija.com/knowledgebase/insert-a-subscription-form-with-php-without-a-widget/):

```
if ( is_page( array( 42,'about-me','Contact' ) ) )
{
    $widgetdata=array (
       'widget_id' => 'wysija-nl-php-1',//form identifier important when many subscription forms on the same page
       'title' => 'Subscribe to our Newsletter',//title of widget
       'instruction' => 'To subscribe to our dandy newsletter simply add your email below. A confirmation email will be sent to you!', // instruction to be displayed on top of the widget
       'lists' =>  array (0 => '1'), //array of list_id to which you want to subscribe your users
       'submit' => 'Subscribe!',//name of the subscribe button
       'success' => 'You’ve successfully subscribed. Check your inbox now to confirm your subscription.',//success message returned when registered
       'customfields' =>array ( //optional array of custom fields to be displayed lastname, firstname, email
            'firstname' => array ('column_name' => 'firstname','label' => 'Prénom'),
            'lastname' => array ('column_name' => 'lastname','label' => 'Nom'),
            'email' => array ('label' => 'Email')
       ),
       'labelswithin' => 'labels_within' //parameter to put the label of the custom field as a default value of the field
    );

    $widgetNL=new WYSIJA_NL_Widget(1);
    $subscriptionForm= $widgetNL->widget($widgetdata,$widgetdata);

    echo $subscriptionForm;
}
else
{
    $widgetdata=array ( /* ANOTHER SETTINGS ARRAY */ );

    $widgetNL=new WYSIJA_NL_Widget(2);
    $subscriptionForm= $widgetNL->widget($widgetdata,$widgetdata);

    echo $subscriptionForm;
}
```

### By widget

Coupling the newsletter with [Widget Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic): 
[image]